# Edit .htaccess file to make file accessible

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I was trying to make a WordPress plugin work, when I found, after hours of debugging, trial, errors and praying ancient Greek gods, that the plugin did not work because it was impossible for the server to reach a particular file.

The website is hosted in a basic shared hosting environment, so the only thing that can be configured is a `.htaccess` file. This file is full of rules but I eventually found which one was causing the issue with the plugin:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(?!themes/.*/core/css/custom\.css\.php$)(.*)\.php$ [R=404,L]
```

When I commented out this rule, the plugin started working normally.

Now, I'm not a server or `.htaccess` expert but the person who coded this rule had some security treat in mind, so I would like to change it so that it simply allows my file to work.

The path of my file is:

```
wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/public/js/service-worker-loader.js.php
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^wp-content/(?!themes/.*/core/css/custom\.css\.php$)(.*)\.php$ [R=404,L]
> ```

*Aside:* As written, this rule/directive is not correct. It is "missing" a second argument. (The third/flags argument will be treated as the second argument and result in requests that match this pattern being erroneously rewritten to the literal "URL" `[R=404,L]` - which is obviously not a valid URL and will likely result in a 404 in a very roundabout way... by WordPress, not Apache.)

I would expect the above rule to have a single hyphen (ie. `-`) as the second argument. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(?!themes/.*/core/css/custom\.css\.php$)(.*)\.php$ - [R=404]
```

The `L` flag is not required here.

(That might seem subtle to the casual reader, but it is a glaring error/typo.)

HOWEVER, you do not need to modify that rule to resolve your issue. (Without knowing more about this, I would avoid editing this rule in case it was a WP plugin, rather than a "person", that wrote it. Although the fact that it is currently "wrong" as written still remains.) Instead, you can just add an additional rule at the very top of the `.htaccess` file to make an *exception* for the file in question. For example:

```
# Prevent further processing when file is requested
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/public/js/service-worker-loader\.js\.php$ - [END]
```

This assumes Apache 2.4. (If you are on Apache 2.2 then use the `L` flag instead of `END`.)

This rule prevents any other mod_rewrite directives in the remainder of the `.htaccess` file being processed when that file is requested.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Would it be possible to place a rule in another htaccess placed in the same directory of the file we're trying to grant access to? Or the higher htaccess takes precedence?

Yes, you can do that. Create another `.htaccess` in the subdirectory and simply disable the rewrite engine. For example:

```
# /subdirectory/.htaccess
RewriteEngine Off
```

Since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, this effectively overrides the mod_rewrite directives in the parent (directory) config. The mod_rewrite directives in the parent are not processed so the request is not blocked.

(Each Apache module is processed differently. Directives from other modules, such as mod_expires, would still be processed in the parent/root config.)

Comment: A real person wrote that line!   :-)  Would it be possible to place a rule in another htaccess placed in the same directory of the file we're trying to grant access to? Or the higher htaccess takes precedence?

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution didn't work (I tried NEW and L, because there's no way to know my Apache version, phpinfo only mentions Apache without printing the version and PHP apache_get_version returns false)

Comment: Now it works, there was a small typo. Thanks very much   :-)

Comment: @LifeafterGuest Yes, you can add another `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory instead if you wish. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @LifeafterGuest "no way to know my Apache version" - unfortunately some shared hosts do restrict this (although you should be able to get more info in your hosting control panel?), but doing so does not provide any additional security, it's just annoying. If you are on Apache then you are likely using Apache 2.4. However, an increasing number of shared hosts use LiteSpeed these days, which is a bit of a hybrid. If you had used `NEW` (instead of `END`) and didn't get a server error then you are likely using LiteSpeed.

Comment: Won't RewriteEngine Off stop any other rewrite? I have many in the "main" htaccess file. When I asked that question I was wandering if <Files> could help. NEW didn't cause errors and I couldn't find infos in the shared hosting panel, while litespeed is mentioned in phpinfo

Comment: @LifeafterGuest Yes, that will stop any other rewrites for requests to that subdirectory. If you are putting this in the `/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/public/js/.htaccess` file then I would have thought that is desirable. Do you have any requests for files in that directory that should be handled by mod_rewrite (seems unlikely)? I would think the `public/js` subdirectory should only contain static assets? A `<Files>` container will not help here. You might be able to use an `<If>` expression to target specific URLs, but that's getting messy IMO (with additional complexity on LiteSpeed).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There are many rewrites, eg. from http to https, from domain without www to domain with www, this RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}], etc. The public/js contains a PHP file that returns an application/js using an header (the file I wanted to grant access to) and other PHP files too